# Matplotlib colorbar own ranges

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap

Is possible to "hard" set ranges between colors in matplotlib colorbar?

Now I am using custom colorbar like this

```
colors = ["#ffffff", "#FFE9E9", "#FFD6D6", "#FFC2C2", "#FFAFAF", "#FF9B9B", "#FF8888", "#FF7575", "#FF6161", "#FF1313"]
cmap= matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(colors)
plt.colorbar(m, boundaries=np.linspace(min(z), max(z), 11))
```

This way creates me this scale:
[image: This way creates me this scale]

Is possible to hard set grey numbers values to green values (create different ranges between colors)?

Comment: I don't think I understand the question. Do you mean this: `plt.colorbar(m, boundaries=np.linspace(0, 1.750, 6))` ?

Comment: @DizietAsahi yes. Can I set more boundaries? for example plt.colorbar(m, boundaries=np.linspace(0, 1, 1.2, 1.750, 5, 5.5, 6)) ?

Comment: Not quite, but `plt.colorbar(m, boundaries=[0, 1, 1.2, 1.750, 5, 5.5, 6])` should work? You should check out the documentation for [ListedColormap](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap.html) and the associated examples. And [`np.linspace()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html) while you're at it.

Comment: @DizietAsahi great. It's working on colormap but is possible to make this boundaries on too plt.contourf ? Because now it's different